# Issue with changing a non-reactive dataframe using reactive elements

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with R Shiny, and this is the problem that I am facing:

I have a dataset (named dataset) that is non-reactive. The user of my shiny app will input a value that denotes the percentage of rows that will be affected.

For example, if the user enters "20", then my server will take a sample of 20% of my dataset's rows, modify 1 column in the row, and put this changed row back into the dataset.

I would also like to eventually print a summary of the original dataset, and then a summary of the changed dataset.

This is what I have done (the `pop` is a user input value):

```
#the number of rows I want to change
popint1 <- reactive({round(input$pop * 0.01 * nrow(dataset)})

#then get the summary of the original dataset
orig_summary <- reactive({dataset %>%
          group_by(age_group) %>%
          summarise(original_cvd_count = sum(as.numeric(s723d)),
                    meanSBP = mean(sb16s, na.rm = T),
                    meanDBP = mean(sb16d, na.rm = T)) %>%
          mutate(new_cvd_count = newRisk(meanSBP, meanDBP) * original_cvd_count)
      })


#then change the 'sb16s' column in a random sample of rows and put the changed rows back
env <- reactive({
        req(dataset)

        dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), popint1()), 'sb16s'] <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), popint1(), seed), 'sb16s'] + 5
      
})


#now get the new summary
int3_summary<- reactive({dataset %>%
        group_by(age_group) %>%
        summarise(original_cvd_count = sum(as.numeric(s723d)),
                  meanSBP = mean(sb16s, na.rm = T),
                  meanDBP = mean(sb16d, na.rm = T)) %>%
          mutate(new_cvd_count = newRisk(meanSBP, meanDBP) * original_cvd_count)
      })

output$summary1 =  renderTable({orig_summary()})
output$summary2 =  renderTable({int3_summary()})
```

But my summary1 and summary2 are shown as the same (talking about the meanSBP column, it should be higher in summary2 since I added 5 to the rows). What mistake am I making and how do I correct it?

Comment: What are you doing with `env`? You don't reference it anywhere else, and it won't modify `dataset` in any way (i.e., the `dataset` you reference in the other reactives).

Comment: @heds1 I only used env to provide a reactive environment, I'm indeed not using it anywhere else. I do not know how else I can change my non-reactive dataset using my reactive ```pop```. Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Comment: `orig_summary` does not depend on any reactive element, so you could just do `orig_summary <- function() { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`env` returns the subset. So, in your reactive summary function you should use `env` instead of `dataset`. To give you an idea:

```
summary_func <- function(df){
         df %>%
          group_by(age_group) %>%
          summarise(original_cvd_count = sum(as.numeric(s723d)),
                    meanSBP = mean(sb16s, na.rm = T),
                    meanDBP = mean(sb16d, na.rm = T)) %>%
          mutate(new_cvd_count = newRisk(meanSBP, meanDBP) * original_cvd_count)
})

env <- reactive({
        req(dataset)
        popint1 <- round(input$pop * 0.01 * nrow(dataset)
        dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), popint1), 'sb16s'] <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset), popint1, seed), 'sb16s'] + 5        
        return(dataset)
})

int3_summary<- reactive({
        env %>%
         summary_func
})


output$summary1 =  renderTable({dataset %>% summary_func})
output$summary2 =  renderTable({int3_summary()})
```

I couldn't test the code, so  there may be some bugs. Please provide a working minimal example next time.